# How to SSH Into Raspberry Pi and Set It Up Headlessly on Kali Linux

Tags: ssh, pi-3b+, headless, kali

I've been using Raspbian for a while now. I came across Kali Linux and I want to use it. I know how to install it, but I don't want to use a HDMI monitor with a keyboard and mouse. Is there a way to headlessly set up Kali Linux without the need of the monitor combo? I also need to be able to SSH into it.

Comment: You can enable ssh using `touch ssh` in boot partition of the SD card.

Comment: And how do I connect it to the internet?

Comment: Using ethernet.

Comment: Any other way? I need the pi to be portable.

Comment: And please write this as an answer.

Comment: See this: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/headless.md

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105085/discussion-between-pradhyumna-narain-and-matej).

Comment: What do you mean by "I need the pi to be portable"? Do you mean that from every place and any location, you could connect to raspberry pi and configure it?

Comment: No, I just mean that no wires should be attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to connect raspberry pi using ethernet and enable ssh by default creating `ssh` file in boot partition. On linux it can be done using `touch /media/$USER/boot/ssh`

If you don't want ethernet you can setup WiFi using `wpa_supplicant.conf` file which location is `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`

Example of WiFi config from raspberrypi documentation:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=<Insert country code here>

network={
  ssid="<Name of your WiFi>"
  psk="<Password for your WiFi>"
}
```

---

More info here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/headless.md 
This link is raspbian documentation but `wpa_supplicant` should be available also in kali linux.

Comment: The link you have given as reference is using Raspbian. Are you sure that is all the same with Kali Linux? If so you should mention it in your answer.

Comment: @Ingo wpa_supplicant should be available also in kali linux. I edited answer.

Comment: OK yes, wpa_supplicant should also be available in Kali Linux. But you should correct the conf location to `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`. That's on the **ext4** partition. For me it is still unclear if an empty `ssh` file in the **fat32** `/boot` directory will also enable the `sshd.service` on Kali Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Try chroot. Plug the SD card into an existing Linux machine. Mount the "rootfs" partition. Let's say the mount point is `/media/user/rootfs`. Then you would type `sudo chroot /media/user/rootfs`. Now you can do everything you want, for example install an SSH server and configure the WiFi. As far as I know, WiFi is set up in the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file, but I'm not sure. You'll have to look that up.

Comment: Is it possible to do it on Windows?

Comment: The chroot command is not available on Windows. You can still try connecting the SD card to a vm. Maybe git bash comes with chroot, you can also try that.

Comment: You cannot do much with a simple chroot. Before you have to `mount --bind ...` important virtual filesystems like `/proc`, `/dev`, `/sys` etc.